# Two async method bind at class

Tags: javascript, async-await, bind

I have Currency Class at currency.js file and i have main.js file

In `currency.js` I want to use `getExchangeRate()` function with 2 parameters (`currency1`, `currency2`) and then I want to bind this function to `convert(amount)` method. I dont want to give `currency1` and `currency2` params to convert method again. Then I want to use convert method in `main.js` like this `convert(currency1, currency2, amount)` but it doesnt work.

```
class Currency{
    constructor(){
        
    }

    async getExchangeRate(currency1 , currency2){
        this.currency1=currency1;
        this.currency2 = currency2
        this.url = `https://api.exchangerate.host/convert?from=${currency1}&to=${currency2}`
        
        const excResponse = await fetch(this.url)
        const excResponseJSON = await excResponse.json()
        return excResponseJSON.result 
    }

   async convert(amount){
    this.amount = amount;
    let value1 = await this.getExchangeRate(currency1 , currency2)
    
    return value1 * amount;
   }
 
}
```

main.js

```
currency.convert("USD", "EUR", 3)
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: why would you expect it to work? `convert()` only accepts a single parameter (`amount`) but you are passing 3.

Comment: i want to bind getExchangeRate() with convert(). So First two param at convert will be getExchangeRate() 's params nad third param is convert()'s  param.

Comment: The you either need to handle it in the `constructor`, create a [curried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) method, or accept all three parameters.

Comment: "*I want to use the method in main.js like `convert(currency1, currency2, amount)`*" and "*I dont want to give `currency1` and `currency2` params to `convert` method*" are exact opposites. You can have only one of them. So what do you really want?

Comment: Btw, there is no good reason to assign `currency1`, `currency2`, `url` or `amount` properties on your instance. In fact, there's not even a good reason to use a `class Currency`, the `convert` and `getExchangeRate` functions should be simple standalone functions.

Answer (score 0):

as @pilchard said, a curried method can "remember" the parameters bcz it returns a scoped function. Maybe something like this?

```
async getExchangeRate(currency1, currency2) {
    
    // ...

    return function(amount) {
        return excResponseJSON.result * amount
    }
}
```